# Cannot resolve GraphUser with 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Could someone tell me if GraphUser is deprecated? If so, what are the alternative ways we can get the GraphUser (or user object) from a GraphResponse?

Note: I tried following dependency but I couldn't resolve it. 
'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'

Cheers

Comment: Try dependency `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'`.

Comment: Tried that too and still no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting GraphResponse in to JSON by response.getRawResponse(). Then I extracted values from the JSON as given below

```
public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("mylog", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                        JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonUser = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //get your values
                            String fullName = jsonUser.getString("name"); 
                            String id = jsonUser.getString("id")

                            JSONObject pictureData = jsonUser.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data");
                            Uri url = Uri.parse(pictureData.getString("url"));
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
}
```

As user data within GraphResponse could be dynamic depending on the query you are passing (eg: "/me/friends?fields=picture,name,id"), this is the best solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
```

Comment: Tried and still no luck